# Eclipse Juno CDT opengl doesnt compile

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I want to develop openGL app using CDT on Eclipse .
I followed [THIS](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/HowTo_OpenGL_C.html) guide.

Now every time I build the program , it print's the [following](http://pastie.org/7800883) :

Now I know this is somehow related to missing libriaries , I even tried to add them via Project -> Properties -> Paths And Symbols -> Libriaries .

There I've tried to add **libglu32.a** , **libglut32.a** , **libopengl32.a** from path *C:\cygwin\lib\w32api* .

Didn't help ...

I run Eclipse Juno 64 bit version , windows 7 .

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: If you are on windows why do you link "libglu32.a , libglut32.a , libopengl32.a" ??? These are Linux static libs.You need windows DLLs

Comment: I use Cygwin.Do I Still need dlls ? If I try to include into libriaries C:\Windows\System32\glut.dll , I get another link error :/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lC:/Windows/System32/glu32.dll makefile:44: recipe for target `cppGL.exe' failed